# C++ stream and operator>> precedence

Tags: c++, operators, iostream

I have the following code snippet:

```
std::stringstream stream("ABC 123 CBA 321");
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map;
std::string key;
```

And I'm trying to read the data like this:

```
stream>>key>>map[key];
```

Which can be rewritten as:

```
operator>>(stream, key).operator>>(map[key]);
```

Considering both `>>` and `.` operators have left to right associativity, can you please explain why `map[key]` evaluates before `key` is read from the stream?

Printing the map:

```
for(auto& it : map)
{
    std::cout<<it.first<<" "<<it.second<<std::endl;
}
```

Results in:

```
 123
ABC 321
```

Yes, there is a space before `123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associativity is irrelevant here. Associativity determines which operands are bound to which operators. It does not determine in which order operand sub-expressions are evaluated. So when you say:

```
a >> b >> c;
```

Associativity dictates that the operands are grouped as `(a >> b) >> c`, but it does not dictate the order in which the expressions a, b and c are evaluated. Before C++17, that order was left unspecified by the standard: this means a, b and c could be evaluated in any order. Since C++17, the order is defined to be a, then b, then c.

In other words, a compiler conforming to C++17 would print:

```
CBA 321
ABC 123
```

Or the other way around, since the container is `std::unordered_map`, but not jumbled words like the output you show.